# Plural form list for all languages in gettext?

Tags: php, gettext

I am implementing a multilingual site in php, while I can use ngettext for getting the correct plural forms depending on language (there are some in which it is not that simple)

My problem is, while I can put several by hand as I know the language, I want to include some basic string from all EU languages (to start with).

My problem is that I can not find anywere a list of plural forms formulas to put them in database for autogeneration of pofiles (and merge when apropiate).

I'll apreciate any hint regarding where I can find that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you're after?

http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/localization-guide/en/latest/l10n/pluralforms.html

Comment: Oh yes! Many thanks, I could not find anything like that to add to default translation templates. You made my day! :)